# How to show multiple websites under single webpage

Tags: html, web-development

I want create one homepage for all my intranet websites, the page will have links on top border & opens different web applications in the area below.

Any idea on how this can be achieved with static HTML or using asp/php technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using HTML iframes might be a simple solution for this

Answer (score 1):

as suggested, use `iframes`

here is a simple [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fkm8v/)

Answer (score 0):

Yhat you are looking for could be called a [Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet_portal). [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) might be the tool for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an iframe. For the links on the page set target attribute of the  tag as the name of the iframe.